# Dotnetnuke JQuery Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dotnetnuke

```
<TD class="CATRow11" vAlign="middle" noWrap align="left" 
    height="100%">$<span id="MRRP" class="CATRow12">100</span><br /><span id="dnn_ctr412_ProductPage_UnitCost"><span class="CATProductListItem"><span class="CATProductListItem">$2,313.29</span></span></span></TD>
```

What I need to do is with JQuery in DNN is change the 100 to a value which is 25% more than the value 2313.29 . Easy to do with jQuery, however I cannot reference the 2313 as I cant get to it, this is a Catalook module so I cannot change the way it renders. Also because it is dynamic sometimes that ctr412 is 409 or 410.

At a loss to see what I can do.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
var tempSpanVal = $('span.CATProductListItem > span.CATProductListItem').val() * .25;
```